# C#-usable RDBMS with synchronization support

Tags: c#, database, synchronization, rdbms

Please suggest a relational database engine usable from c#, with synchronization (replication) support. Ideally, it should be also cross-platform. We're dealing with two databases - centralized and local (when network connection is not available) and changes must be synchronized between these two, with conflict resolution. 
Something like CouchDB replication, but in relational world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've used SQL Server and SQLCE to perform this functionality.

You can define how, when, and what gets synchronized, and if it's a one-way or two-way sync, and all sorts of other fine goodies.

The only problem (from your questions POV) is that it's not cross-platform.

That said, the synchronization system is not, in and of itself, that complex. It's just a matter of CRUD statements, with the appropriate timestamps and ability to recognize things on the appropriate keys, and of course a GRAVEYARD table which allows for tracking of deletes.